# Which one of the following in not part of a Beowulf cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing

I need an answer for this,

**Which one of the following in not part of a Beowulf cluster?**

1. Windows.
2. Linux.
3. MPI.
4. IP Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Cluster.

You can eliminate the other options using: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster  (Paragraph 3)

I think a simple google search could have answered the question.

Comment: No, if you read the citations and references below, you will know that windows is a part of it.